# WSL bash in Visual Studio Code running .bashrc but not .bash_profile

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Until recently, when I've launched the integrated terminal in Visual Studio Code, bash runs both my .bashrc and my .bash_profile files.  But now it's only running the .bashrc file.  I need it to run both.

Some details: VSC 1.70.1 (latest), with the "Remote - SSH" extension, running under Windows 10 (updated) with WSL 2 installed.  When I launch a Microsoft terminal, it runs both .bashrc and .bash_profile, but VSC's integrated terminal only runs the former.  This probably means I have s.t. wrong in my VSC config, but the settings there seem to change frequently and it's hard to keep up.  The relevant parts *seem* to be

```
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "WSL",
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "bash":{
           "path": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\bash.exe",
           "args": ["-l"]
    },
    "WSL": {
           "path": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\wsl.exe",
           "args": [ ],
           "icon": "terminal-ubuntu"
    }
},
```

but that doesn't work, nor do any of the variants I've tried on the two "args" parameters, nor changing the `defaultProfile` to `"bash"` instead of `"WSL"`.

Before I give in and put all my startup settings in my .bashrc file and get rid of my .bash_profile file, what do I yet lack?

Comment: My understanding of the .bash_profile is that what you set or change in it only gets set upon login whereas the .bashrc file you can make whatever changes you want and source the file to get the updates into your session. I only use the bashrc file.

Comment: I admit to being confused about the diff between .bashrc and .bash_profile; for one, I'm not sure what constitutes "logging in".  Judging by how terminals work (Microsoft's as well as others I've used over the years), it's any time you start up a new terminal (including a new tab in a tabbed terminal), at least that's when the bash_profile gets read.  EXCEPT in VSC.  But yes, maybe I should solve this by just using a bashrc file...

Comment: The idea is that `.bash_profile` (traditionally on UNIX) runs once when you log in (and sets environment variables that can be inherited by subprocesses), whereas `.bashrc` runs every time you start an interactive shell (and sets up state local to that individual shell). This is the difference between the intended use cases of `bash -l` and `bash -i`. (Note that MacOS does not follow this convention; there, every new terminal tab has its own login shell).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I've heard that explanation, but somehow I'm not grokking it.  If I'm on Windows using WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux), what does it mean to "log in"?  I'm pretty sure the .bash_profile does NOT run when I log into Windows.  It does run in MsTerminal *every* time I start a new terminal, but it never runs when I start a new terminal in VSC.  Do the term and VSC have different notions of what it means to "log in"?  

Anyway, sounds like best thing is to scrap my .bash_profile and put it all in my .bashrc.

Comment: I was talking about how UNIX has traditionally worked for background to explain why bash has these two configuration files. Nothing in my comment purported to describe WSL's actual behavior. That said, consider keeping both files but sourcing `.bash_profile` from `.bashrc`.

Comment: Ok, I did that (source .bash_profile from .bashrc) and now it works as I want in both the Microsoft terminal and in VSC.  I had previously set it up the opposite way (source .bashrc from .bash_profile), which did not work.  Thanks for the tip--if you want to put your comment as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce this after even after upgrading to 1.70.1, so I'd recommend trying out these things:

- try

  ```
   "path": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\wsl.exe",
   "args": ["-e", "bash", "-li"]
  ```

  to make sure that a login shell is started
- if this changed after upgrading, read `Help -> Release Notes` to find out what might be responsible, e.g. the [Shell integration is now enabled by default](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_70#_shell-integration-enabled-by-default), so you might try `"terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.enabled": false`
- sync / backup your settings, re-install vanilla VSC, check if behaviour is still the same

Comment: I confirm that adding the args you give, namely
`"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {      "WSL": {
        "path": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\wsl.exe",
        "args": ["-e", "bash", "-li"],
        "icon": "terminal-ubuntu"
      }
    }`
works.  FWIW, I found nothing in the Release Notes that explained this change in the way VSC works, but I also didn't read the last few months of those Notes thoroughly...

Comment: Happy to help. If this solved your problem, please mark this as accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

The historical presumption on UNIX is that `.bash_profile` runs once when you log in, then `.bashrc` runs in each new shell. Thus, things that are inherited by child processes (like environment variables) go in `.bash_profile` so they can only run once per login (often, as a parent process to `xinit` or otherwise GUI startup), whereas things that need to be separately configured for each new shell (like aliases, non-exported functions, prompt settings, etc) go in `.bashrc`.

If, however, you're in an environment where `.bash_profile` isn't run during session creation, you might want to invoke it during `.bashrc` operation (so it happens during setup of any new interactive shell). Consider adding the following to your .bash_profile:

```
# put this at the top of your .bash_profile
[[ $profile_already_sourced ]] && return
declare -x profile_already_sourced=1 # export so we only run once per process tree

# ...set up your environment variables here...

[[ -s ~/.bashrc ]] && source ~/.bashrc
```

...and the following to your `.bashrc`:

```
# put this at the top of your .bashrc
[[ $bashrc_already_sourced ]] && return
declare -- bashrc_already_sourced=1 # do not export this!

# ...do your non-exported shell-local configuration here...

[[ -s ~/.bash_profile ]] && source ~/.bash_profile
```

...that way you can have each file source the other when needed without causing an infinite loop.

Comment: I'm going to accept Max's answer, although I confirm that this one works too.  The reason is that since my previous settings for .bashrc and .bash_profile work everywhere *except* in VSC's integrated terminal, I think it's better to make the change in VSC rather than in the bash files.  I do appreciate your help, though!